# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Code Golf's [third moderator election](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Wheat Wizard] [image: HyperNeutrino] [image: Jo King]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4856246717906944/0).

Comment: I'm honoured to help serve the community! Yay!

Comment: Congratulations everyone!

Comment: I never knew Doorknob was a whole crew! (Anyway thanks @Doorknob for keeping things ticking over.)

Answer (score 19):

All I can say is

## Congratulations to our new moderators!

I‘m sure that you will all do a wonderful job, and I look forward to seeing the site improve under your moderation!

It’s a shame I missed out, but I‘m very happy to have lost to the 3 of you, as I know you‘ll all be excellent moderators.

Answer (score 19):

Thank you very much and congratulations to Wheat Wizard and Jo King as well! I look forward to working with both of you and Doorknob to regulate and improve this site and I am honored to have been chosen to serve CGCC as one of your new moderators.

From my time here on this site, I hope my experience will allow me to reflect the values and practices of the community, and being new to Stack Exchange moderation, I will do my best to support the desires and needs of the community and I would greatly appreciate feedback on any actions I take.

I am excited to continue my time in this community as one of your moderators now. I invite anyone to contact me at any point (you can use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)) if you believe I should be doing a better job or if you have suggestions or concerns with my moderation, as I hope to provide the best experience for the community and its members.

Comment: Man, JHT is gonna be weird telling a moderator how to golf their code :P